# remove custom taxonomy base / slug

Tags: custom-taxonomy, slug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove slug in taxonomy url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42120/remove-slug-in-taxonomy-url)

I'm using proreview theme and it uses a custom taxonomy called "review-cats"

In of this

www.domain.com/review-cats/clothing

I want

www.domain.com/clothing

I've been trying to find a solution for 2 days not ...

relevant code

> register_taxonomy(
>
> "review-cats",
>
> array("reviews"), 
>   array(
>   "hierarchical" => false,
>   "label" => "Categories",
>   "singular_label" => "Category",
>   "rewrite" => true
>   )
>   );

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box, nor is it advisable, and for good reason. If you really did want to do this you would need to hack the core files.

Why it's not a good idea:

- WordPress does not check for Permalink clashes between taxonomy term slugs and page slugs
- Say you have a page with the slug `clothing`, and a taxonomy term `clothing`, and you go to example.com/clothing ? Does the user want the page? Or the term? There's no way of telling!

Doing this is opening a can of worms for yourself.

Instead I recommend you use the rewrite parameter to redefine the slug as `'reviews'`. Note that setting the slug to `''` will not do what you desire, even though it seems like it should.

e.g.:

```php
register_taxonomy(
    "review-cats",
    ["reviews"],
    [
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "label" => "Categories",
        "singular_label" => "Category",
        "rewrite" => [
            'slug' => 'reviews'
        ]
    ]
);
```

I also recommend you use a generator to create your taxonomy and post type code. Go here:

http://themergency.com/generators/

Comment: thanks for the quick answer how is it possible for standaard categories to remove the slug? there has to be some way...

Comment: I **strongly** advise against this. It would make more sense logically and semantically not to do this. You gain nothing by doing this, and you leave yourself with new problems where before you had none. If for whatever reason this is necessary and unavoidable, please explain

Comment: for Seo reasons, Its easier to get google rank on keyword search of clothing when its www.domain.com/clothing then www.domain.com/review/clothing

Comment: hmmm I've seen no evidence at all that this actually works, as I understand it, it's the distance from the homepage via clicks, not the number of characters in the URL that matters. I suggest you refer to this and only this for SEO and Wordpress: http://yoast.com/articles/wordpress-seo/

Comment: Also bear in mind what you're asking for has many, many pitfalls that could utterly destroy your site, e.g. a taxonomy term called wp-admin would make your dashboard innaccessible etc

Comment: Ill be naming my taxonomies in dutch so no chance of that happining, do you know how its done tho? I really think it does make a difference for page ranking